# Why does $\frac{\textbf{g}^T\textbf{d}}{\textbf{d}^T\textbf{H}\textbf{d}}$ give the maximum of function $\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d})$

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

Let say I have to find the value $\lambda^*$, that maximizes the following quantity:

> $$\lambda^*=\underset{\lambda\in \Lambda}{\text{arg
>  max}}\;\;\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d}),$$

where $\textbf{x},\textbf{d}\in \mathbb{R}^n,\;\lambda\geq0$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is a quadratic function.  I read from a [paper by Bottou and Lin](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/lin-2006.pdf) (page 12) that:

> Since $\mathcal{D}$ is a quadratic function,
>   $\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d})$ is shaped like a parabola.
>   The location of its maximum $\lambda^*$ is easily computed using
>   Newton's formula:
>
> $$\lambda^*=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d})}{\partial
>  \lambda}\biggr\rvert_{\lambda=0}}{\frac{\partial^2\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d})}{\partial
>  \lambda^2}\biggr\rvert_{\lambda=0}}=\frac{\textbf{g}^T\textbf{d}}{\textbf{d}^T\textbf{H}\textbf{d}},$$
>
> where $\textbf{g}=\nabla\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x})$ is the gradient
>   vector and $\textbf{H}$ is the hessian of $\mathcal{D}$.

I tried searching for  a derivation for this but so far I didn't find any. So my question is: Why does

$$\underset{\lambda\in \Lambda}{\text{arg
 max}}\;\;\mathcal{D}(\textbf{x}+\lambda\textbf{d})=\frac{\textbf{g}^T\textbf{d}}{\textbf{d}^T\textbf{H}\textbf{d}}\;\;\;?$$

A derivation would be nice :) Thank you for any help!

Comment: They denote what you get from the Newton's formula $\lambda^+$ rather than $\lambda^*$. They first find the unconstrained maximum which is $\lambda^+$, and then check if it is in the interval $\Lambda$. If it is in the interval the $\lambda^*=\lambda^+$ otherwise $\lambda^*$ is at one of the endpoints of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Aah okay, so the equation follows simply by taking the derivative of $\mathcal{D}$ w.r.t $\lambda$ and equating to zero? In the unconstrained case I mean :)

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Roger that @S.B. :) It wasn't so hard after all x) Thank you, P.S. if you want to post your comment as answer I can accept it.

Comment: I think it is fine the way it is. However, it would have been better if you made your corrections in a way that people can see that the question is corrected/modified.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. What do you want me to do? I'm not sure what you meant exactly :) P.S. I changed the question back to the way it was before you commented :) Thank you

Comment: It's fine. You can simply add a sentence in the end titled **update** or **edit** and mention what was your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second order Taylor epansion we get
$$
\mathcal D(x+\lambda d) =
\mathcal D(x) + \lambda g^T d + (1/2)\lambda^2 d^T H d  + O(\lambda^3)
$$ 
Taking the partial derivative regarding $\lambda$ we get
$$
F(\lambda) = \frac{\partial \mathcal D(x+\lambda d)}{ \partial \lambda} =
g^Td + \lambda d^THd + O(\lambda^2) \quad (*)
$$
It seems they continue with a Newton Raphson iteration step to find a root, using initial value $\lambda_0=0$:
$$
\lambda_{n+1} = \lambda_{n} - \frac{F(\lambda_n)}{F'(\lambda_n)} \Rightarrow \\
\lambda_1 = 
-\frac{F(0)}{F'(0)} =
-\frac{g^Td}{d^THd}
$$
which is the claim except for the sign. If we neglect the $O(\lambda^2)$ terms in $(*)$, we get the same.

Comment: The different sign is bothering me, maybe I should do a sample calculation.

Comment: Thank you, the reference material is in my post if you want to see it :)

Comment: Interesting topic, machine learning. I found nothing obvious. This would need more work from my side getting into the paper.

Comment: Thank you :) Appreciate it